# How can i Get rid of this flutter override errors?

Tags: flutter, dart, overriding

I'm getting deprecated API usage error. How do I resolve it? Here is the stack trace is given below.

```
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Users\sabah\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_core-0.4.3+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\core\FirebaseCorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Users\sabah\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\device_apps-1.0.9\android\src\main\java\fr\g123k\deviceapps\DeviceAppsPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Users\sabah\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_admob-0.9.0+10\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebaseadmob\AdRequestBuilderFactory.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Users\sabah\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.12.11\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\cloudfirestore\CloudFirestorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Users\sabah\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.12.11\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\cloudfirestore\CloudFirestorePlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: C:\Users\sabah\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_analytics-5.0.9\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebaseanalytics\FirebaseAnalyticsPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Users\sabah\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_messaging-6.0.9\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebasemessaging\FirebaseMessagingPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Users\sabah\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_database-3.1.1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\database\FirebaseDatabasePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.        
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.      
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: C:\Users\sabah\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\path_provider-1.5.1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\pathprovider\PathProviderPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
C:\Users\sabah\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences-0.5.6+2\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\sharedpreferences\SharedPreferencesPlugin.java:25: warning: [deprecation] getFlutterEngine() in FlutterPluginBinding has been deprecated
    setupChannel(binding.getFlutterEngine().getDartExecutor(), binding.getApplicationContext());
                        ^
1 warning
Note: C:\Users\sabah\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\share-0.6.3+5\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\share\SharePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.        
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Users\sabah\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\video_player-0.10.5+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\videoplayer\VideoPlayerPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Those warning messages are coming from the packages that you use inside your flutter project. As long as those dependencies be as same, you can't get rid of them.

### Solution

1. Ask for help on the respective git repositories.
2. Fork and do the work yourself